# Changing the theme color of class" well" in bootstrap

Tags: css

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:30px;"  id="subscriber_page">
      <div class="well">
        <form> 
             <h3> Subscribe Now! </h3>
              <label for="Name"> FullName </label> 
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input fullname here" id="name" required/>
              <br />
              <label for="Name"> Address </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input full address here" id="address" required/>
              <br /> <br /> <br />
             <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button></center> 

           </div>
        </form> 

    </div>   

 </div>
```

Hi there, can someone help me with the bootstrap theme well in a login page? I don't like the current color of the well in bootstrap. Is there another way I can change the color on it? I tried some CSS code but it didn't work.

I already tried the following:

```
.well{
  background: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **!important** after color

`.well{
  background: #000 !important;
}`

Comment: thank you ! :) the !important thing is working hehehe